# NodeJS Express and EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, ejs

I'm using NodeJS/Express and EJS to create a form to an API route. But I'm having a trouble connecting my post route(which contents an id) with the ejs form. How can i add the id to the ejs.

This is my post route

```
router.post('/:id/new', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {   //here i'm trying to add project id to the url 
    //const project = await Project.findById(req.params.id)
    const releasenoteData = {
        user : await req.user._id,
        
        title: req.body.title,
        path: req.file.path,
        originalName: req.file.originalname,
        description: req.body.description,
        createdAt: req.body.createdAt,
    }
    try {
        const releasenote = await ReleaseNote.create(releasenoteData)
        console.log(releasenote)
        res.redirect('/')
    } catch {
        if (releasenoteData.path != null) {
            res.redirect('/new', {
                errorMessage: 'Error Creating the Release Note'
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Now I want to connect the above post route with a ejs form and get the relevant data from it. How can I do that with the project id in the route.

```
<form action="/new" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  //here before new id should be added i think 
    <label for="text">Title: </label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
    <br><br>
    <label for="file">File: </label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required>
    <br><br>
    <label for="text">Description: </label>
    <input type="text" id="description" name="description">
    <br><br>
    <label for="date">Upload Date: </label>
    <input type="date" id="createdAt" name="createdAt">
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Add Release Note</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Drop the `action` part from your form, it POSTs to the address it was first GET from (assuming you have the `get` that corresponds to this `post`)

Comment: Great, will post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, confirmed by the OP as a working solution, is to drop the `action` part of the form. This makes the form POST to its default location

As per the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm):

> [...]

> 10. Let action be the submitter element's action.

> 11. If action is the empty string, let action be the URL of the form document.

This means that if the form is first GET, `action` can be omitted and the url is preserved (actually this is handy if the url contains multiple parameters).